# Tensorflow Image scaling and rescaling inconsistency when displaying loaded images using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, computer-vision, tensorflow2.0

I am looking at this code and I cant seen to figure out why the image rescaling is not wrong.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

IMAGE_SIZE = [256, 256]

files = ["<add_an_image_location>"]

def decode_image(image):
    image = tf.io.read_file(image)
    image = tf.io.decode_png(image, channels=3)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [*IMAGE_SIZE])
    image = (tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 127.5) - 1  # this I understand, the image is being converted to be in range [-1, 1]
    image = tf.reshape(image, [*IMAGE_SIZE, 3])
    return image


def load_dataset(filenames, labeled=True, ordered=False):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)
    dataset = dataset.map(decode_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    return dataset

ds = load_dataset(files, labeled=True).batch(1)

example = next(iter(ds))

plt.imshow(example[0] * 0.5 + 0.5)  # this I cant seem to figure out!
```

I realise and understand this would work `plt.imshow(((example[0] + 1) * 127.5)).numpy().astype('uint'))`

Cant seem to understand why this works `plt.imshow(example[0] * 0.5 + 0.5)`

Similarly -

```
(tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255) - 0.5  # scaling so

plt.imshow(example[0] + 0.5)  # and rescaling so works
```

I have a feeling that I am missing something silly.. but.. please someone help me!! :D

Comment: Please share with us what `example` is - that's where the (true) problem might lie. Other details might not be relevant in that case - see [How to post a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @medium-dimensional Apologies, I assumed the code was running. I have now made the code reproducible. Also, `example` is an image from the dataset that I want to display